# Is there something wrong with this scallop residue?

Tags: food-safety, shellfish, scallops

After cooking scallops in oil in non-stick pan, I cleaned up and there was a white hard substance left stuck to the pan. It felt like plastic. These scallops were fresh caught one day before using, right from the boat.  Also, when beginning to cook they had blue around the outer edge. Suggestions?  We are wondering if there is a problem here!

Answer (score 1):

Comments in [this blog comment](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/475205#4480198) could offer a clue to the blue color. The most relevant part says:

> The blue color in the liquid is due to a change in the natural
>   chemical composition of the scallop meat during spawning.

That doesn't explain the hard white stuff, but maybe it'll put you on the right track. If there's a state or university agricultural extension near you, they might be able to shed some more light on the mystery.